# Center without fixing width?

Tags: css

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/W86yx/

I want to get rid of the 300px in .center. I want all 3 div/p under main to be centered. How do I do that without fixing width? I'd like the div/p above .tblInsideHere to be more centered. The div/p should align since the width is the same (same text). Then tblInsideHere should start more to the left and end more to the right of the previous div/p. How do I center this?

css:

```
.main {
    background-color:green;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    background-color:pink
}
.tblInsideHere > div {
    float: left;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="center">
        blah 
        <span> blah text</span>
        <span> blah text</span>
    </div>
    <p class="center">
        blah 
        <span> blah text</span>
        <span> blah text</span>
    </p>
    <div class="tblInsideHere center">
        <div>blah text blah text</div>
        <div>blah text blah text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/W86yx/2/) what you want?

Comment: Can you create an image that shows exactly how you want it to look?

Comment: @jasonslyvia: Actually, yes it IS. Except I'm trying to make the text align left again and it looks like it may work (still playing in live editing on my site)

Comment: @jasonslyvia: I'll accept it as an answer if you copy/paste the css style

Comment: @SamuelNeff: Jason got it. text-align:center + display:inline. I just had to text-align:left the inner dom element and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glad to help :)

```
.main {
    background-color:green;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.center {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:pink
}
.tblInsideHere > div{
    display:inline-block;
}
```